# Count number of rows that fulfill multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c(1:20),
                  Ethnicity = c(rep(c("White", "Asian", "Black", "Hispanic", "Other"), times=20/5)),
                  Age = c(1:20),
                  Set = rep(c(1,2,3,4), times=20/4)
)
```

What is the most efficient way to count the number of rows that have `Ethnicity`== 'Asian' and `Set` == 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're measure of efficiency is but

```
sum(df$Ethnicity== 'Asian' & df$Set == 3)
```